# Confused by the custom link component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, routes, react-props

I just start learning react and next js, I am working on the link component, I got basic routing of next.js which is straightforward, but then I came across this code:

```
import NextLink, { LinkProps as NextLinkProps } from 'next/link';
```

what is NextLink? I always thought it is just import link from "next/link"....and the rest code is also confusing, can you point me to a direction to understand this code?

```
const Link: React.FC<NextLinkProps & { className?: string }> = ({
    href,
    children,
    ...props
  }) => {
    return (
       <NextLink href={href}>
         <a {...props}>{children}</a>
       </NextLink>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

Answer (score 2):

When importing default exports (i.e. the ones without the {}) you can name them whatever you want without using "as". So 'import Link from "next/link"' is the same as 'import NextLink from "next/link"'. Basically what you are looking at is a custom component which wraps an anchor tag in a Next Link. The author renamed Link to NextLink because the custom component is already called Link and it would have been a duplication.

Comment: wow that totally make sense, thanks Alex. What about <a {...props}>{children}</a>? why put <...props> over there ?           for <NextLink href={href}> I think I know, it means href is prop to be passed right

Comment: This way any props that are given to the wrapper will be also passed to the anchor element. For example you can pass a style or className to the wrapper and it will style the inner anchor element.

Comment: oh ok, that makes sense ... so NextLinkProps is a built-in stuff from next/link? and the author rename it as LinkProps? I never heard className can also be props, thats why it threw me off lol